# supervisord unknown error making dispatchers for : ENOENT

Tags: supervisord

The supervisord config as below, **myserver** is golang executable put into dir **/usr/tci/bin**. And it indeed existed in the dir,  why I still get the **ENOENT** error? **ENOENT** means can't find the entry.

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel=debug

[program:myserver]
command=/usr/tci/bin/myserver
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Error msg:

> 2018-03-05 08:39:00,230 INFO spawnerr: unknown error making
>   dispatchers for 'myserver': ENOENT

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the directory that holds your log files exists.

Supervisor was running when I removed its log directory `/var/log/supervisor`.
I first noticed the issue when I tried to restart a process which resulted in 
an `unknown error making dispatchers for ENOENT` error

I readded the directory by running:
`mkdir /var/log/supervisor`

This fixed the issue and allowed me to restart my process sucessfully. I would also imagine a

`sudo service supervisor restart`

would fix it since it might generate the missing directory.

Make sure you have `logfile` set then restart the server:
`sudo service supervisor restart`

My logging config:

`loglevel=debug
logfile =/var/log/supervisor/myserver.log`
`

Laravel example config:

[image]